# Handling async functions in react action

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, callback, react-redux

I'm using react-places-autocomplete package, with the function geocodeByAddress. It should return the coordinates of an address, if the search action is triggered.

Here i my code:

```
export function handleSearch(address){
    console.log("handleSearch searching for address: " + address )
    var LAT = '';
    var LNG = '';
    const request = geocodeByAddress(address,  (err, { lat, lng }, result) => {
        var res = "";
        if (err) {
            console.log('Oh no!', err);
            res = 'Oh no! Something went wrong :(';
        } else {
            console.log(
                `iYay! got latitude and longitude for ${address}`, { lat, lng });
            res = `Yay! got latitude and longitude for ${address}: ${lat}, ${lng}`;
        }
        LAT = lat;
        LNG = lng;
        console.log(result);
    });
    console.log("request", request);
    return {
        type: 'SEARCH_EVENT',
        payload: {"lat": LAT, "lng": LNG}
    };

}
```

I know it does not work, because as I undestand geocodeByAddress is async and the callback function is executed later. How to deal with that? I know that it would be nice to use react-pormise with axioms but in this case I don't have a promise.

Thanks and best regrads.

Comment: Came up with the idea calling handleSearch from geocodeByAddress in the container. But still not sure if this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).  It lets you handle asynchronous actions very easily.

```
export function handleSearch(address){
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("handleSearch searching for address: " + address )
        var LAT = '';
        var LNG = '';
        const request = geocodeByAddress(address,  (err, { lat, lng }, result) => {
            var res = "";
            if (err) {
                console.log('Oh no!', err);
                res = 'Oh no! Something went wrong :(';
            } else {
                console.log(
                    `iYay! got latitude and longitude for ${address}`, { lat, lng });
                res = `Yay! got latitude and longitude for ${address}: ${lat}, ${lng}`;
            }
            LAT = lat;
            LNG = lng;
            console.log(result);

            dispatch({
                type: 'SEARCH_EVENT',
                payload: {"lat": LAT, "lng": LNG}
            });
        });

        console.log("request", request);
    }
}
```